# How to use Interface Builder to set up a UITableView that links to another window

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder

Can I only use Interface Builder to set-up a UITableView that links to another view? Does this require code to do so?

Comment: @0x7fffffff On what exactly? I am new to using apple's development tools.

Comment: Are your table cells static, or dynamically generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a lot of interface based stuff without coding, you could easily make some kind of recipe book, or something like that without any code... Just by using a storyboard.

In fact this is a great tutorial on how to make a recipe book using a storyboard, without code.
http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at storyboards? You can do a lot of the UI navigation stuff (including the one you asked for) without any code. You may want to check out the tutorial at http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1